# How to make es6 import start working using tern_for_vim

Tags: javascript, vim, ternjs

I've installed [tern_for_vim](https://github.com/ternjs/tern_for_vim), configured everything using also `.tern-project`:

```
{
  "plugins": {
    "node": {},
    "es_modues": {}
  },
  "libs": [
    "ecma5",
    "ecma6",
    "browser",
    "ecmascript",
    "react",
    "underscore"
  ],
  "ecmaVersion": 6
}
```

and now, when I try to import let's say `underscore` in this way:

```
underscore = require('underscore')
```

autocompletion for `underscore.` works perfectly, but when I import in a modern way:

```
import underscore from 'underscore'
```

autocompletion for `underscore.` doesn't work. How to fix it? Any clues?